# NodeJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, json, response, authorize.net

The `body` of the response from Authorize.net's sandbox API is:

```
{
  "messages": {
    "resultCode": "Error",
    "message": [
      {
        "code": "E00012",
        "text": "You have submitted a duplicate of Subscription 5777085. A duplicate subscription will not be created."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but when I go to parse it:

```
try {
   bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
} catch (ex) {
   console.error(ex);
}
```

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

And this: `console.log(response.headers['content-type']);`

returns this: `application/json; charset=utf-8`

What am I doing wrong? I want to parse the JSON into a JS object.

Comment: Your code does not prove what you claim, so at the very least, add a `console.log(body)` before that try block so you can prove to yourself that `body` contains what you think/claim it contains.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually you didn't see it, but there was a invisible unicode character, specifically the byte order mark at the beginning of the JSON.
Since the byte order mark is not a valid JSON character, JSON.parse rejected it.
[image: byte order mark image]
To remove, use the following code.

```js
function removeByteOrderMark(str){
    return str.replace(/^\ufeff/g,"")
}
// OR (faster),
let removeByteOrderMark = a=>a[0]=="\ufeff"?a.slice(1):a
```

Comment: Interesting, how do I o about parsing it with this character?

Comment: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/JSON-API-Response-ERROR/td-p/59351

Comment: @orangeMint I added a function to remove this character to my answer.

Comment: @smileycreations15 you saved my day!

Comment: @PatNeedham No problem! :D

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue with `JSON.parse()` in a project we're working on. We're just using `JSON.stringfy()` and the object was working fine, but on the other platform where we received the data it had a similar error **"Unexpected token in JSON at position 1"**.

Here's how we made it work:

1. In NodeJs we encoded the stringified object using `encodeURI()` then sent it
2. On the client side: decoded the string then used `JSON.parse()` on the decoded string

**Analysis**:

I tried to print the characters from the position, then replaced it with an empty string, then we realized it prints other weird characters even after replacing them. After that I realized it's an HTML code `"&quot;"` so instead of replacing it we went for encoding the string it and decoding.

**We tried it on our case and it's working no problems**